# Visibility in viewport

Tags: modeling, visibility

Newbie to Blender, working my way through Blender Bros tutorial.
Despite having visibility turned off on all objects I can still see some. If I select them nothing is highlighted in the scene collection.
I've moved over from Modo and still find my fingers on auto for shortcuts, so I don't know if some of these have caused this effect but can't figure out how to sort out.
Using M1 iMac running OS 13.4.1[image]
Attached screen grab.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Try hilighting one of the objects in the viewport then hovering over the outliner and hitting the '.' (period) key either on the main keboard or the numpad. That should expand the tree and hilight the object in the outliner.

Answer (score 0):

try pressing the little flag button in the outliner:[image]

and press the little viewport button, this should give you another way to disable visibility, but only in the viewport, and will not affect any render
[image]

Comment: also posting the blend file is very helpful for issues

Comment: Hi, How do I post the file. New to this site.

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow the instructions on that page. However you can only share files up to 30Meg in size there so if yours is larger you'll have to find another site and post a link to the file there.

Comment: Thanks, file uploaded.

Comment: You haven't added a link to it so we can't download it!

Comment: Sorry. Anyway, it's sorted now. Don't understand why they were visible when all visibilty icons were turned off but fixed by copying to new collection then deleting objects.